# Can somebody help me understand this door chime wiring?

Tags: wiring, uk, doorbell

I have this inside an old door chime which seems redundant. (UK)

[image: 4 core bell wiring]

I plan to decommission this door chime, but would like to understand the wiring first. Particularly if it is connected to the mains somewhere.

These wires runs deep into the house and I can't trace the end of them. There were batteries inside too, but they were flat and show signs of leaking.

I can't get any voltage from them with my multimeter (but as I said, bell is dead anyway). What would they likely run to? What does the colour coding mean?

Comment: can you check for continuity between the battery contacts and the wires?

Comment: There is none. Although battery acid may have damaged that

Comment: there is no color coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the batteries were there it probably did not have mains power connections. I have installed a few battery chimes and they last amazingly long time. Yours looks like a 2 location version (front door back door). I have not seen a chime that uses mains power that also required batteries , they may be out there but if you have a front door button and back door button I would bet that’s all there is no mains connections.

Comment: That's interesting thanks. So you reckon each pair ran to a separate button? Would explain why no juice present

Comment: Yes that would be normal the front door may have had a “ding dong” and the back door just a “dong” very common, electronic chimes like I have play a longer tune for front and a short tune for rear.